# Type hints for generic code

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, type-hinting

Let's say, I have this piece of code:

```
class BaseModel(object):
    pass

class AppleModel(BaseModel):
    pass

class OrangeModel(BaseModel):
    pass

def get_record(model, pk):
    try:
        result = model.objects.get(pk=pk)

        # Some code working with BaseModel..

        return result
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Now, I want to use it like in this example with proper type annotation...

```
myApple = get_record(AppleModel, 12)
myApple. # type hints for AppleModel

myOrange = get_record(OrangeModel, 433)
myOrange. # type hints for OrangeModel
```

How should I annotate the `get_record` function? I tried something like

```
def get_record(model: Type[BaseModel], id: int) -> Optional[BaseModel]:
    # ...
```

But then, I lose info about subclasses. I tried to use [Generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic), but without success.

Comment: I think you would need to annotate the variables `myApple` and `myOrange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want to do is have `get_record` accept the type of some subclass of `BaseModel`, and return an instance of the corresponding class.

In that case, you'll probably want to use [TypeVars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) -- in particular, [TypeVars with an upper bound restriction](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#type-variables-with-upper-bounds).

That would look roughly like this:

```
from typing import Type, Optional, TypeVar

# ...snip...

T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseModel)

def get_record(model: Type[T], id: int) -> Optional[T]:
    # ...
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks a lot! :-)